# Sending input/parameters from iPhone to Computer?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, bluetooth

I have an iPhone app built with PhoneGap (driven by AngularJS) that scans and processes barcodes just the way I want it to. I also have a webapp (also powered by AngularJS) that needs to accept barcode input and do similar processing. Since using a webcam to scan a barcode is not very elegant and I don't want to buy a barcode scanner for the computer running the webapp, I am trying to use the iPhone to scan a barcode (which already works) and send that data to my web application. Can anybody

I have thought about tethering the iphone to the computer with bluetooth, but have no idea how to send/receive bluetooth data through JavaScript. Should it be over wifi and use the AngularJS $http service?

Comment: It wouldn't be too painful to create a node.js server to relay that information.

Comment: Yea, you're going to need a backend of some sort. NodeJS is great with Angular, websockets work great too.

Comment: So i've been doing node.js tutorials trying to make progress on my own. This is what i'm understanding from you guys: 1) I run the server on the same machine that's running the web app. 2) Have the iPhone send the barcode info to the server--assuming the iphone and computer are on the same network this will be to a port on the localhost right? 3) relay the barcode info from the server to the web app. I'm not sure how I'd code step 3 but I just wanted to check that I'm following what you guys said.. let me know if I'm way off. Thanks!

Comment: step 3 would be the easiest for me. Just use plain and simple js. So if you have nodejs setup with mongo, just attach a clientid (some id that will tie your phone and webapp to the relay), store the barcode data and that id in a mongodb, and then fetch it with this code I've supplied you. http://jsbin.com/ojuhAHu/2/edit?js

Comment: Basically, you would be creating an api, that way you could access that data from anywhere. (iPhone, web, android, etc.) See this fairly primitive, but helpful api tutorial. http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSockets and a library like Pusher:

http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start

It allows events to fire based on execution on another page. So on your scan success callback you can trigger an event which can send information to another web page simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still trying to imagine how I'd implement a node.js server to do what i want (told you i'm new :/) but this is some great info...  Every time I'm on stackoverflow my faith in humanity is temporarily restored haha.

Comment: That's great, we all love to share the knowledge :)